# Pushing ads to wifi hotspot users

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I have WiFi network with highpseed antennas to my area which covers almost 70-80 peoples. 
Iwould like to generate some revenue through Advertisements placed on the hotspot login websites that they visit.

Is it possible to display ads from Any ads provider  to the wifi login website.

The question is how to generate ips address for etch users with deferent dns and ip and proxy because ads providers can accept all users traffic from one ip because i have only one internet modem adsl

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Nginx and HTTP injection?

Answer (score 0):

Use squid. See this thread: http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Inject-some-html-with-transparent-squid-td4665224.html
You will have to forgo any illusion of it being pretty, though. Users can be tracked using their session cookie, I assume you have a captive portal in place. For windows users, you can utilize WPAD, see http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2012-07&post=WPAD-Man-in-the-Middle for a primer. That
may or may not trigger AV.

Answer (score -1):

You could feed the clients (faked) DHCP-responses when IP-renewals take place. This way you can also change the DNS of the client machines, because most operative systems use auto-configuration with DHCP per default, this becomes very dangerous on WiFi-networks. Because on WiFi the packets flow in the air-space, thus if you have the ability to response faster than the AccessPoint/Router... Then it is possible to make yourself the proxy/router before routing back & forth the traffic as normal, and injecting whatever you'd like live. The chain then becomes like this:

{Victim} <-> {You} <-> {WiFi-Router} <-> {Internet}

Good luck.